# Remove used element from array after using math random

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to work on quiz with multiple answers but I don't want to display the same questions twice, as there are 4 possible answers.
How can I delete an item from an array after using math random?

```
var answers = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'kiwi'];
      document.getElementById("firstOption").innerHTML = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
      document.getElementById("secondOption").innerHTML = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
      document.getElementById("thirdOption").innerHTML = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
      document.getElementById("fourthOption").innerHTML = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
```

So I want 4 different options, but this is just randomly picking values from the array and sometimes are the same.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using splice method as soon to remove particular element from the array once it has been used.

Sample code:

```
var answers = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'kiwi'];
var randomElement = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
document.getElementById("firstOption").innerHTML = randomElement;
var index = answers.indexOf(randomElement);
answers.splice(index, 1);
```

Find complete code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hgobgk8t/21/).

Comment: Thanks! Do you think this code could be shortened in any way?

Comment: I didn't think much about code size, for sure it could be improved

Comment: everything except "firstOption" etc. is constant so you can move it in a fuction

Comment: Thanks again! That doesn't look so 'grim' anymore :D

Comment: Perfect. Welcome! :)

Answer (score 2):

just shuffle the answers array, and apply the values in order to the nodes

```js
function shuffle(arr){
  for(let i=arr.length, j, tmp; i > 0; ){
    tmp = arr[j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i--)];
    arr[j] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = tmp;
  }
  return arr;
}

function mix(){
  var answers = shuffle(['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'kiwi']);
  
  [...document.querySelectorAll('#firstOption, #secondOption, #thirdOption, #fourthOption')]
    .forEach(function(node, index){
      node.textContent = answers[index];
    });
}

mix();
```

```html
<ul>
<li id="firstOption"></li>
<li id="secondOption"></li>
<li id="thirdOption"></li>
<li id="fourthOption"></li>
</ul>

<input type="button" onclick="mix()" value="mix"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just swap current randomly selected question w last index of current random range

Here the implementation for above algo

```
var answers = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'kiwi'];
let currentLastIndex = 4;
let random;
while(last > 0) {
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentLastIndex--);
    console.log(answers[random]); //replace this with required code
    swap(answers, currentLastIndex, random)
}
function swap(arr, firstIndex, secondIndex) {
    let temp = answers[random];
    answers[random] = answers[last];
    answers[last] = temp;
}

sample run 
['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'kiwi'] //question array
let random = 1 //banana selected
['apple', 'kiwi', 'orange', 'banana'] //replace banana with kiwi
let random = 1 //kiwi selected
['apple', 'orange', 'kiwi', 'banana'] //replace kiwi with orange
let random = 0 //apple selected
['orange', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'banana'] //replace apple with orange
let random = 0 //orange selected
['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'kiwi'] //orange apple with orange
//done
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to sort the array randomly / shuffe the array before writing to DOM.

Hit **run snippet** repeatedly to see the random order of items.

```js
var answers = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'kiwi'];
var el = document.getElementById('options');

answers
  .sort(shuffle)
  .forEach(function(item) {
    var option = document.createElement('div');
    option.innerHTML = item;
    el.appendChild(option);
  });

function shuffle() {
  return Math.random() - Math.random();
}
```

```html
<div id="options">

</div>
```